# Four color theorem in D3js for neighbors polygons coloring?

Tags: d3.js, colors, maps, gis, graph-coloring

Jason Davies graph coloring didn't avoided me to get neighbors polygons with the same color.

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(d.color = d3.max(neighbors[i], function(n) { return countries[n].color; }) + 1 | 0); });
```

**Four color theorem:**

We know :

> the **four color map theorem** states that, given any separation of a plane into contiguous regions, producing a figure called a map, no more than four colors are required to color the regions of the map so that no two adjacent regions have the same color. (wikipedia)

[image: Four color theorem in action]

and:

> Second, for the purpose of the theorem every "country" has to be a simply connected region, or contiguous. [...] Because the territory of [non-contiguous countries] must be the same color, four colors may not be sufficient. (wikipedia)

Still, **Is there any four color theorem-like implementation/function available for #D3js so we get neighbors polygons with different coloring ?** (so we don't go to use 20 colors since 4-6 are generally enough)

**See also:**

- [Four color theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem)
- [Graph theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)
- [Jason Davies Graph theorem coloring example](http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/4188334)
- [D3 coloring](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category10)

Note: tag #four-color-theorem may be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mind 8 colors? Reducing the number of possible colors is pretty simple:

```
color.range(color.range().slice(0, 8));
```

http://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/5899035

7 colors results in some adjacent countries sharing a border.

I also tried sorting the countries by number of neighbors before coloring; 7 colors still don't work:

```
var permutation = d3.range(neighbors.length).sort(function(i, j){ 
  return neighbors[j].length - neighbors[i].length; });

countries = d3.permute(countries, permutation);
neighbors = d3.permute(neighbors, permutation)
              .map(function(array){ 
                return array.map(function(d){ 
                  return permutation.indexOf(d); }); });
```

Are you trying to color a specific map? It might be easier to set up a color scheme ahead of time instead of trying to code an algorithm that each client runs.

Comment: Adam this link is broken

Comment: I was googling d3 four-coloring! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such implementation. D3 wouldn't be the best thing to implement it in either in my opinion, as its design largely assumes that the data are independent.